# Is there a Google Map API which returns a polygon that maps the boundary for a specific location?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap, geofencing

I want a set of coordinates representing a polygon around a region like given by `OpenStreetMap`. Does google map provide any similar API?
I found a similar implementation on `OpenStreetMaps` API which provides a polygon for a specific area like this [example](https://safeimuslim.github.io/gmaps-geofence/).

Comment: If you expect automatic city/region boundaries as Polygon from Google Maps API, the answer is **no** and this has been asked dozens of times here. There is an open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953) which has been there since 2008 (!) and which Google obviously didn't want to implement in the past... 12 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by MrUpsidedown there is no Google API for automatic city/region boundaries as Polygon from Google Maps API but I integrated nominatim of OSM with Google Maps to get the desired functionality.